# retrieve date failed in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I defined my mongoose schema like this

```
var personSchema = new Schema({
    id: 1
    data: [{
        dob: Date,
        gender: String,
    }]
});
```

Then I do

```
Person.find({"data.dob": new Date('1-2-2016')}, function(err,result) {
    res.json(result)
  });
```

I got empty array, any clue why? I also tried

```
Person.find({"data.dob": "1-2-2016"}, function(err,result) {
        res.json(result)
      });
```

Comment: First query looks okay. Can you show us the doc you are trying to fetch in mongodb ? Also can you try new Date('2016-01-02') instead ?

Comment: Do you actually have somebody in your DB with that date?